# How to change size of UICollectionViewCell inner elements?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a UICollectionView with 3 custom views inside each UICollectionViewCell. I need to make these 3 views bigger in one cell, but I couldn't find a way to access size properties of these views. Is there any way to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AaronBrager `-(void)layoutSubviews { self.firstView.bounds.size.height = 50; }` returns an error "Expression is not assignable"

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks a lot!
`-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect cardbounds = self.firstView.bounds;
    cardbounds.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    self.firstView.bounds = cardbounds;
}`
Actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're subclassing UICollectionViewCell, you can resize them in `layoutSubviews`. If you're building the cell in your controller, you can assign the subviews a tag, and get them later using `viewWithTag:`.